# `git push` showing error. Cannot push to `git://`. Try `https://`

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a repo and the following error is being thrown on terminal.

```
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/<username>/<repoName>
  Use https://github.com/<username>/<repoName>
```

I have done some config changes in few days ago and I do not remember what I have done I have changed something related to this `https://` and `git://` but I have no idea how can I make this thing work again.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated because I botched the command before...**

What you presumably changed is the remote URL.  To fix it

```
git remote <remote-name> set-url https://github.com/<username>/<repoName>
```

should do it.  (For `<remote-name>` probably it's `origin`.  I'm assuming you know the real values for `<username>` and `<repoName>`...)

Comment: They are not changing, the remote urls. After I am executing this command, and again checking the remote using `git remote -v` they still remaining same with `git://`

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up the command.  I believe I've fixed it, but I don't deal with remote changes much so could still have a mistake.  If this doesn't work you could just remove the remote and then re-add it (with the correct URL)